# How do I update a useState value when using useContext?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

Im trying to update a useState thats in a context component, from inside my index.tsx file. I'm trying to use useContext to make it global. I'm getting no errors but I noticed that the update for the state dosent set the state (There is nothing saved inside useState).

**In context component **

```
import { Message } from "@/pages/api/sendMessage";
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useContext, useState } from "react";

const MessagesContext = React.createContext<Message[]>([]);
const MessagesUpdateContext = React.createContext<
  Dispatch<SetStateAction<Message[]>>
>(() => []);

export function useMessages() {
  return useContext(MessagesContext);
}
export function useMessagesUpdate() {
  return useContext(MessagesUpdateContext);
}

export function MessagesProvider({ children }: any) {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Message[]>([]);

  return (
    <MessagesContext.Provider value={messages}>
      <MessagesUpdateContext.Provider value={setMessages}>
        {children}
      </MessagesUpdateContext.Provider>
    </MessagesContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Imported them to Index.tsx file:

```
import {
  MessagesProvider,
  useMessages,
  useMessagesUpdate,
} from "@/components/MessagesContext";
```

Made custom hooks

```
  const messages = useMessages();
  const setMessages = useMessagesUpdate();
```

But when Submit is ran the useState isnt updated.

```
  function submit() {
    const message: Message = {
      role: "user",
      content: textInput,
    };
    **setMessages([...messages, message]);**
    setTextInput("");
    sendMessages([...messages, message]);
    setHideExamples(true);
  }
```

I have a useEffect that should put a message inside the state as soon as the sites rendered, but i checked with console.log(messages) and there is none.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!hasSentInitialPrompt) {
      const initialPrompt: Message = {
        role: "system",
        content:
          "Test Test Test",
      };
      setMessages([...messages, initialPrompt]);
      sendMessages([...messages, initialPrompt]);
      setHasSentInitialPrompt(true);
    }
  }, [hasSentInitialPrompt]);
```

PS.

This all worked when i had the useState in index.tsx file so the problem is with the useState not anything else

Comment: Are you wrapping the children inside `MessagesProvider` component?